# Use ISO time and date format in KDE 5

Tags: linux, kde, date-time

I've been using Dolphin for organising pictures. I would like to see the modification time and date displayed in ISO format. It is easier to read for me. I used to be able to configure that in KDE 4:

[image: KDE4 time format widget]

In KDE5 the widget has been replaced by this:

[image: KDE5 time format widget]

Is there a way to configure this in KDE5?

Comment: On my system (Open Suse Leap 15.0) I specify ISO format in the KDE Time format settings, but Dolphin just ignores it and uses dd/mm/yyyy! Very irritating!

Comment: There is an old bug for this that was closed in 2018, but since this is still occuring in Kubuntu 22.04, I've re-opened it: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=360643

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I find **en_SE** to be fully ISO-compliant:
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM (24h)

Whereas for me *en_DK* uses DD/MM/YYYY HH.MM (24h) which is not ISO compliant both in the date order (it's simply a western europe order) and in the time separator.

*en_CA* uses YYYY-MM-DD hh:MM (12h) likewise close but uses AM/PM rather than 24h.

Tested on KDE Plasma 5.11.3, running on Arch Linux.

EDIT 2021-11-08: If  en_SE is not present in your system, in the comments to this answer Kael Watts-Deuchar has steps to create it manually.

Comment: I've been using that, and it is fine in KDE. However, the rest of the system does not have an en_SE locale, which causes problems with many programs.

Comment: The full label for en_SE is "Sweden - English (en_SE)"

Comment: en_DK used to work for me, but now it does the date backwards (DDMMYYYY).

Comment: I had to add en_SE manually, using the link from [this comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/langpack-locales/+bug/208548/comments/11).

Put it in `/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_SE`, replace `"en_SE:2000"` with `"i18n:2012"`, then run `sudo locale-gen`

Comment: Oh I also had to add `en_SE.UTF-8 UTF-8` to `/etc/locale.gen`

Comment: en_SE does the short format correctly, but it does d mon yyy in its long format. Austrailia (wbp_AU) uses the yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM for the short format, and yyyy Mmm d for the long format, which, while annoying, isn't as bad as writing day or month first.

Comment: en_SE is unfortunately gone in recent versions. Why is there no simple ISO 8601 locale in KDE ? That would solve all those complaints.

Comment: @dargaud: you should still be able to manually create it from http://www.stacken.kth.se/~auno/en_SE following Kael's instructions above

Comment: Sounds good but `locale-gen` seems to ignore it.

Comment: This situation is stoopid.  I'm not in Sweden.  Why must I lie just to have ISO compliant dates?  Also, this solution messes up the long format.

Comment: unfortunately that is also not ISO compliant, as the seconds and timeoffset are missing. And yes this is entirely stupid

Answer (score 7):

No that is impossible. Is is not possible to manually set the formats like it was possible in KDE4. You always have to choose a locale for each category (Number, Time, Currency, Units, Collation)

Unfortunately installing a more standards compliant locale (like en_DK or en_NL) does not help. KDE5 uses its own list of locales, ignoring the system locales.

For the desktop clock you can set the date and time format apart from the system format in newer version of KDE 5.

Answer (score 4):

```
vi /usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.digitalclock/contents/ui/DigitalClock.qml
- dateLabel.text = Qt.formatDate(main.currentTime, main.dateFormat);
+ dateLabel.text = Qt.formatDate(main.currentTime, "dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

Taken from https://www.ulduzsoft.com/2017/08/custom-date-configuration-in-kde-plasma-digital-clocks/

**UPD 2021-Aug**

In new versions of Plasma (5.18+ or earlier, I don't remember exactly when it appeared) added format setting via GUI

1. Mouse2 on clock widget
2. Configure digital clock
3. Select the "Custom" option in the "Date format" dropdown
4. Fill it according https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#formatDateTime-method
   [image]

Comment: Sorry but this is not what the question asks.
At the most, you could put this as a comment.

Comment: This worked for me to change the short time format in icons only task manager in KDE 5.20 on Debian 11. But, has increased boot time by around 13 secs.

Comment: @NaveenReddyMarthala loot at update

Comment: loot? i didn't understand you @cetver.

Comment: I mean "look", find UPD 2021-Aug in the answer

Comment: The update still does not answer the question how to set the date format in *Dolphin*.

Answer (score 2):

One locale which uses ISO 8601 timestamps is **en_DK**.

I'm guessing KDE 5 returned to the POSIX *locale* mechanism for consistency. KDE 4 was the odd one – practically all other programs use the POSIX-format locale settings, with predefined formats. (This means the settings will be understood by non-KDE programs, too.)

---

If KDE doesn't list en_DK, grep the output of `locale -a` to check whether the `en_DK.utf8` item is available. If it isn't, on Debian/Ubuntu you should be able to add it via `dpkg-reconfigure locales`. On other distributions, if there is `/etc/locale.gen`, add (or uncomment) the following lines to it:

```
en_DK.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_DK ISO-8859-1
```

Run `locale-gen` to rebuild.

---

If KDE *still* doesn't list en_DK despite `locale -a` showing it, you should still be able to set it globally. The above formats correspond directly to POSIX locale environment variables:

- Region → `LANG`
- Numbers → `LC_NUMERIC`
- Time → `LC_TIME`
- Currency → `LC_MONETARY`
- Units → `LC_MEASUREMENT`
- Sorting → `LC_COLLATE`

The system-wide location for these varies. Often you can set them via `localectl`:

```
localectl set-locale LANG="en_US.UTF-8" LC_TIME="en_DK.UTF-8"
```

Sometimes you'll have to edit `/etc/locale.conf`, `/etc/default/locale`, or similar.

Per-user, the same can be set in `~/.pam_environment`, `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, or similar.

Comment: I cannot find en_DK on the list (it's sorted by name and the only Danish is Danish dk_DK). The widget was there since I can remember, at least KDE3.

Comment: I found that en_GB has an acceptable (day-month-year) layout.

Comment: I tried en_DK, but saw no change from en_GB.

Comment: I checked, and it doesn’t use POSIX locales *at all*. Which can be verified by seeing that the Plasma5 UI contains elements (e.g. `ksh_DE`) that are not present in `/usr/share/i18n/locales`. A `find / -iname '*ksh_de*'` does not even return any results. Bad KDE. BAD. Sit!

Comment: en_DK used to work, but now it has the date format backwards (DDMMYYYY). en_SE (Sweden - English) is currently sorted correctly (YYYYMMDD).

Comment: @EL_DON: My glibc 2.28 does not have en_SE at all.

Answer (score 1):

I found that selecting `Canada - Canadian English (en_CA)` makes the short format ISO:

- 2017-09-15 12:26 PM
- Friday, September 15, 2017 12:25:34 PM GMT

Comment: Unfortunately, speakers of other languages can not use this.

Answer (score -1):

en_SE works great for me. There's also the en_se package available in the AUR to install it system-wide.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).